# T-SQL: Row_number() group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a structure as below:

```
create table #temp( deptid int, regionid int)

insert into #temp
select 15000, 50
union
select 15100, 51
union
select 15200, 50
union
select 15300, 52
union
select 15400, 50
union
select 15500, 51
union
select 15600, 52

select deptid, regionid, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY regionid ORDER BY deptid)       AS 'RANK',
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY regionid ORDER BY deptid) AS 'ROW_NUMBER',
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY regionid ORDER BY deptid) AS 'DENSE_RANK'
from #temp

drop table #temp
```

And output currently is as below:

```
deptid  regionid    RANK    ROW_NUMBER  DENSE_RANK
--------------------------------------------------
15000   50          1       1           1
15200   50          2       2           2
15400   50          3       3           3
15100   51          1       1           1
15500   51          2       2           2
15300   52          1       1           1
15600   52          2       2           2
```

My requirement however is to `row_number` over `regionid` column but by grouping and not row by row. To explain better, below is my desired result set.

```
deptid  regionid    RN
-----------------------
15000   50          1                   
15200   50          1              
15400   50          1                   
15100   51          2              
15500   51          2                   
15300   52          3                   
15600   52          3
```

Please let me know if my question is unclear. Thanks.

Comment: you want the dense_rank() over (order by regionid) without the partition then?

Comment: Ok I used DENSE_RANK() over (order by regionid) and it gives me desired result. Thanks :)

Comment: @ZLK:please post that as answer,so that it can come under answered questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dense_rank() over (order by regionid)` to get the expected result.

```
select deptid, regionid, 
 DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY regionid) AS 'DENSE_RANK'
from #temp
```

Partitioning within a rank/row_number window function will assign numbers within the partitions, so you don't need to use a partition on regionid to order the regionids themselves.